# Password generator question bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to make a bash script that will ask the name of the user, favorite food and the current date and save these to the variables food, date and name a random password will then be generated. When the user forgets the password all he has to do is enter the same name (userrecovery), favorite food (foodrecovery) and the date (daterecovery) when the password was generated and the password should be shown.
The code i use to generate a random password:

```
choose() { echo ${1:RANDOM%${#1}:1} $RANDOM; }
  pass="$({ choose '!@#$%^\&'
   choose '0123456789'
   choose 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   choose 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   for i in $( seq 1 $(( 4 + RANDOM % 8 )) )
      do
         choose '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
      done
  } | sort -R | awk '{printf "%s",$1}')"
```

I tried something like:

```
if [ $food=$foodrecovery -a $date=$daterecovery -a.... ]
   echo $pass
```

This works but when i close the script and reopen it will generate a new password which it shouldnt.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run the script `pass` is executed. You should wrap it into a function like you do `choose()`. For example:

```
genpass()
{
 pass="$({ choose '!@#$%^\&'
   choose '0123456789'
   choose 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   choose 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   for i in $( seq 1 $(( 4 + RANDOM % 8 )) )
      do
         choose '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
      done
  } | sort -R | awk '{printf "%s",$1}')"
  echo "${pass}"
}
```

On another note;

The use of `$RANDOM` should be avoided ([Reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html)) for password & encryption key generation.

The following is simpler and cryptographic-ally stronger;

```
choose(){ echo "$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c16)" }
```